# Is there a programmatic equivalent of gnome-terminal's 'Set Title ...' on-command title change?

Tags: bash, title, gnome-terminal

I know setting $PROMPT_COMMAND in Bash can set the terminal title every
time a command is run. What I would like to do is to programmatically
change the title under control of the operator *without*
un-setting $PROMPT_COMMAND. I believe this is the same behavior as
gnome-terminal's 'Set Title ...', because, otherwise, the title would change
immediately after a user changed it. It is as if gnome-terminal ignores
the escape sequences that are set in $PROMPT_COMMAND (or in a printf statement
or whatever) once a user enters a title via 'Set Title ...'.
I'd like (to make this harder!) to also exclude 'xdotool' or any other
add-on packages that might not be installed on a standard Linux box.

Any suggestions? This might be better directed at the 'gnome-terminal' folks,
but I thought I'd throw it out to the world first, in case there is a known
solution.

Thank you.